# jQuery mouseenter() and mouseleave() functions work repeatedly

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a picture and a div. The div is hidden(display:none;). I want to show the div when mouse is over the picture and hide the div again when mouse is not over the picture. I use mouseenter() and mouseleave() events to do this but when moue is over the picture, both of the functions work repeatedly. Here is the code that I define functions:`

```
$("#pic").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#checkin").slideDown();
});
$("#pic").mouseleave(function(){
  $("#checkin").slideUp();
});
```

I also tried the hover method but the result is the same.

```
$("#pic").hover(
  function(){
    $("#checkin").slideDown(200);
  },
  function(){
    $("#checkin").slideUp(200);
  }
);
```

What is the problem, I can't understand.

**Update:**
Here is the HTML code

```
<tr><td valign='top' class='checkinpic'><img src='img.png' id='pic' height='100%'></td></tr>
```

...

```
<div id='checkin'>
You are not going to any activity this week.
</div>
```

Comment: And the div is probably covering the image, so the mouseleave event is triggered, then it hides, and the mouseenter event triggers. Common issue.

Comment: @Baris Demirel your code is working fine with the hover function http://jsbin.com/webec/1/edit.

Comment: @adaneo Yes, it is. I did not think of it. Then, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. When I changed the element that works with the mouseleave event, it worked:

```
var block = false;
$("#pic").mouseenter(function(){
if(!block) {
    block = true;
    $("#toggleDiv").slideDown(400, function(){
        block = false;
    });
}
});
$("#pic").mouseleave(function(){
if(!block) {
    block = true;
    $("#toggleDiv").slideUp(400, function(){
        block = false;
    });
}
});
```

Thank you for your help.

**Update:**
I noticed that giving both the picture and div a class and defining the mouseenter and mouseleave events of the class is a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

May fix something like this:

```
var block = false;
$("#pic").mouseenter(function(){
    if(!block) {
        block = true;
        $("#toggleDiv").slideDown(400, function(){
            block = false;
        });
    }
});
$("#pic").mouseleave(function(){
    if(!block) {
        block = true;
        $("#toggleDiv").slideUp(400, function(){
            block = false;
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BnPJ4/

Comment: Yes, it solved the repetition problem, but now, mouseleave function does not work. So it works for one time, until the div is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution edited from ur code, hope it will help full for u.

```
$("#pic").hover(function() {
    $("#checkin").slideDown(200);
},
function() {
    $("#checkin").slideUp(200);
});
```

click the link below to run the code

http://jsfiddle.net/ByZ2z/5/

Comment: The same problem continues, I want the div to show over the picture, that's why it repeats.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but... I think I can add my 5 cents here:

In my experience, a lot of things and subtleties go under the bridge when you have to properly implement a solution delivering mouseover/mouseleave functionality.

*Since you are already using jQuery and relying on it doesn't mean you need to incorporate a new library into your code*, I suggest you consider `hoverIntent`, which will basically take care of things like users accidentally/quickly passing the mouse through a given element. The script will basically try to understand if the user had the intention of actually hovering an element, and it will possibly ignore it in case it was a very quick action.

The implementation of hoverIntent is also very easy.

[Here is where you can find the script](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent).

On your code, you can simply refer to the `jquery.hoverIntent.min.js`file.

Now, the implementation is as simple as:

```
    $("#pic").hoverIntent({

      // hover is on
      over: doSomething(),
      
      // hover is off
      out: doSomethingElse();
      },

      timeout: 50
    });
```

`timeout` allows you to calibrate the reaction time of your script (whether quicker or lazier to respond to user's hover action).